# How can I remove "View Cart" button that appears after adding a product in the cart on a custom page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have used the  "add to cart" shortcode for a product on a custom page. But I want to remove the "View Cart" button that appears after clicking the "Add to Cart" link of the product.

Comment: Could You Please share your site link then i will check about this issue

Answer (score 0):

add this code to function.php

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'remove_message_after_add_to_cart', 99);

function remove_message_after_add_to_cart(){
    if( isset( $_GET['add-to-cart'] ) ){
        wc_clear_notices();
    }
}
```

Comment: use this code in your style.css of your child theme->
 .button.wc-forward {
    display: none !important;
 }
 
 //where  button.wc-forward ->inspect button view cart/ write here class name

Answer (score -1):

Im no pro on this so I don't know how it might affect your code, but this is what I did to solve the issue.

Find the file: inc\woocommerce\woocommerce-config.php 
Line 699 (in my case)

$array['view_cart']         = esc_attr__( 'View cart', 'oceanwp' );

Replace 'View cart' with ''